# how can I count elements till found N good elements?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a collection.

I want to project from it only first N that are not deleted.

However I want to count how many elements (deleted and non-deleted)
I traversed till got to the Nth non-deleted element.

How can I do it?
i thought to use side effect:

```
int i;
collectiom.Skip(Convert.ToInt32(startIndex))
            .TakeWhile( x=> 
{
++i != 0; 
return (!x.IsDeleted)
})
            .Take(N);
```

But the compiler refuses.
And now I see it's not answering my need anyway

TIA

Comment: can you give an example of input data and desired result?

Comment: Using LINQ is never a requirement... don't complicate your life (and code) by using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @Ed S - I agree with your sentiment, but in this instance I think Linq solves the problem nicely. (I was trying to solve this problem without using Linq, but my non-linq solution didn't come close to the readability of Andrew Cooper's answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
var selected = collection.Select((x, i) => new {Item = x, Index = i})
                         .Skip(Convert.ToInt32(startIndex))  
                         .Where(x => !x.Item.IsDeleted)
                         .Take(N);
```

The result is a sequence of `N` anonymous objects where `x.Item` is the original object, and `x.Index` is its index in the original collection.  If you want to start counting the original collection from `startIndex` just swap the `Select` and `Skip` calls.

You can then get the number you want like so:

```
var numberProcessed = selected.Last().Index + 1;
```

Comment: +1 this is absolutely a `Where`/`Take` scenario - it's not a `TakeWhile`

Comment: After reading this the third time, I finally see how brilliant this is.  I wish I could give you +2

Comment: @Andrew - just to be clear, to satisfy OP's question—take first N items, but count how many total items you had to pass to get there—you could leave off completely the `.Skip(Convert.ToInt32(startIndex))`???

Comment: @Adam The only reason the `Skip` is in there is because it was in his solution, so I assumed he was wanting to skip some members of the collection before he started working on collecting the `N` elements to be retrieved.  This would make sense in a paging scenario.  If this isn't a requirement then you're quite right, just omit the `Skip` call altogether.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst what is the difference between Where\Take?

Comment: [Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) is like a SQL `TOP`; it just means 'I don't want all the items, just the first 10'. [Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) is like a SQL `WHERE`, and means 'I don't want all the items, just the ones where the condition is met'. You use take when you want a certain number of items, and you use where when you want all the items that match your condition.

Answer (score 2):

Does the whole thing have to be with linq?

Here's a saner attempt :)

```
List<thing> result = new List<thing>();
collection.ToList().ForEach(x => {
   if (!x.IsDeleted && i < N){
      result.Add(x);
      i++;
   }
});
```

Comment: You might also want something like `if (i > N) break;`

Comment: @Kirk - actually, on second thought, I don't think you can put a break there

Comment: I wasn't sure and I haven't tried it, but you probably don't want to iterate the whole collection.

Comment: @Kirk, yeah, if that's computationally expensive then naturally you could put in a regular foreach loop with a break.

Comment: Saner?  I think LINQ makes the intent of the code easier to read.

Comment: @Andrew - usually it does.  I use linq all the time.  I meant OP's original attempt was less than sane, your answer is very clear, and better than my old-school loop.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
        IEnumerable<Thing> result = collectiom.TakeWhile((x, index) => {
            if (numNonDeleted == N)
                return false;
            if (!x.Deleted && ++numNonDeleted == N)
                numIveBeenThrough = index + 1;
            return true;
        }).Where(x => !x.Deleted).ToList();
```